# Python 3 How to find the different combinations of a String

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, combinations

Given a String is there any short way in Python 3 to find the different combinations of the space seperated words in that string ?

For eg:

If the input string is 'Peaches Apples Bananas', I want output as:

'Peaches Apples Bananas'

'Peaches Bananas Apples'

'Apples Bananas Peaches'

'Apples Peaches Bananas'

'Bananas Peaches Apples'

'Bananas Apples Peaches'

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [`itertools.permutations`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
import itertools

for perm in itertools.permutations('Peaches Apples Bananas'.split(' ')):
    print(' '.join(perm))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools

string = 'Peaches Apples Bananas'
word_list = string.split(' ')

output = [' '.join(permutation) for permutation in itertools.permutations(word_list)]
```