# how to calculate Permutations from a range of 3 to 7 characters

Tags: python-3.x, string, combinations, permutation

I have searched here:
[Python 3 How to find the different combinations of a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17264773/python-3-how-to-find-the-different-combinations-of-a-string)
and found this function:

```
import itertools
string = 'Peaches Apples Bananas'
word_list = string.split(' ')
output = [' '.join(permutation) for permutation in itertools.permutations(word_list)]
```

Actually I have this example of a string
'N A E C H S W'
and am selecting characters from 3 up to length of string
I have done so with a for 3 in range of (3, length) and another for ....

```
j =0 
while j < 4:
    for i in range (3+j,lng+1):
        scpy = word_list[j:i]
        scpy_tx =""
            for k  in scpy:
            scpy_tx = scpy_tx + str(k)
        print(i, j, scpy, scpy_tx)
    j= j +1
```

giving this output:

```
3 0 ['N', 'A', 'E'] NAE
4 0 ['N', 'A', 'E', 'C'] NAEC
5 0 ['N', 'A', 'E', 'C', 'H'] NAECH
6 0 ['N', 'A', 'E', 'C', 'H', 'S'] NAECHS
4 1 ['A', 'E', 'C'] AEC
5 1 ['A', 'E', 'C', 'H'] AECH
6 1 ['A', 'E', 'C', 'H', 'S'] AECHS
5 2 ['E', 'C', 'H'] ECH
6 2 ['E', 'C', 'H', 'S'] ECHS
6 3 ['C', 'H', 'S'] CHS
```

This input I provide to the a.m. permutation formula:

```
output = [' '.join(permutation) for permutation in itertools.permutations(scpy)]
```

My approach is however missing many combinations, as i.e. not all nedded charactars are considered yet:

```
'N A E S'  'N A E S W'  'N A C H W'
'N E C H'  'N A S'  'N H W'
```

and others are not given as in put to the üermutation formula.

How can I calculate all possible permutations with length from  3 to 7 for all given characters?

Currently I have no good idea; and my mathematics are/were newer that deep.

Comment: What's wrong with `[''.join(perm) for r in range(3, 8) for perm in itertools.permutations('NAECHSW', r)]`

Comment: sorry; I am new with this materia and was not aware of the 2nd argument

Answer (score 1):

`permutations` has a second argument for the length, you can just iterate over that for each length you want, and collect them together with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import permutations, chain

chars = 'NAECHSW'
all_perms = chain.from_iterable(
    permutations(chars, perm_len) 
    for perm_len in range(3, len(chars)+1)
)
for p in all_perms:
    print(''.join(p))
```

Using `chain` makes `all_perms` fully lazy so it won't use up any extra memory.

Comment: thank you.
meanwhile I used the collections.Counter:
And found a function isSublist(sub, main).
A will habe a look again to the permutations appraoch in due time:
Fist let me say thanks for your good help.